# How to change field value from a Views block?

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I have a content type named "Tasks" and it has a boolean field simple on/off checkbox. It controls tasks for done or not done.

I have a views block to list all task assigned to me.
I want to control this checkbox field from this block like this:

[image]

When I click the checkbox beside Task 1 it's value should change. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) Module. The module provides a field to be editable when displaying using views.